# bluebird coroutine - error while running two ajax requests at the same time

Tags: ajax, bluebird, coroutine

I am working in the browser and want to run two ajax requests at the same time - NOT in sequence. So I yield an object or an array like so:

```
// yield object
Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  var data = yield {
    tweets: $.get('tweets.json'),
    profile: yield $.get('profile.json')
  };
  console.log(data.tweets, data.profile);
})();

// yield array
Promise.coroutine(function* () {
  var [tweets, profile] = yield [$.get('tweets.json'), yield $.get('profile.json')];
  console.log(tweets, profile);
})();
```

But this blows up with the error:

```
A value [object Object],[object Object] was yielded that could not be treated as a promise
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: What about: `Promise.all([$.get('tweets.json'), $.get('profile.json')]).then(console.log.bind(console))`